# Are there pressure vessels with hand inserts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure

I'd like to work with some bike-tire parts while at moderate pressure (60 psi), so I'm hoping to use a pressure vessel, but it has to be transparent and have inserts so I can use my hands to manipulate the inside.  Something like this:
[image: Aerosol Containment Chamber]
however that's a medical chamber, so it can't handle higher pressure.

Are there pressure vessels with hand inserts, or is there a technical problem preventing them from existing?

Comment: The reason I can't work with the parts under standard (1 atm) pressure are that some of them are far too large.  I need the 60 psi environment to keep them at a manageable size.

Comment: So what you want is a hyperbaric chamber with reinforced gloves allowing you to work inside. How detailed is the work you are planning? Threading needles is unlikely - how would you pick up the thread or needle? fitting a 20mm nut to a bolt is more achievable.

Comment: This might be feasible to a very limited extent, but only if higher pressure is outside. When you have greater pressure inside, it will blow any flexible gloves out of the compartment. With 60 psi pressure difference and 20 cm hole diameter, the glove will push out of the box with approximately 130 N of force. There might be some kind of multistage solution for this, limiting the unbalance section area to your forearm section after you insert the hand (at this point you might want to have an off switch which you can operate with both hands in the box ;)).

Comment: Redesign the higher pressure chamber with higher thickness (adding steel frames along edges if needed ), after calculating the plate bending stresses.

Comment: how would you keep circulation in your hands going with 60 psi acting on your hands? ... the pressure may even force air that is trapped inside the gloves into your bloodstream

Comment: @SolarMike Not very detailed.  Imagine if you received bike tubes pre-inflated and without valves; this currently wouldn't work because they're huge if they're not inside a tire, and there is no workable way to squeeze them into the tire at atmospheric pressure.  But in a pressurized environment, it would be doable.

Comment: @jsotola My blood pressure is 130/75 so I'm sure I can keep going just fine at 60psi.  Also, 60psi is 4 atm, so... consider diving under water: you gain 1 atm of pressure for every 33 feet you dive under water, so the pressure under water at 100 feet (30m) is already 60psi.  Yet the world record free dive is more than 430 feet, where pressure is around 200psi... and if someone can withstand 200psi without equipment, then surely I can withstand 60.

Comment: the rest of your body would not be at 60 psi ... I am only guessing that there would be some problems

Comment: Re your complaint about my comment "not very detailed" - check out the difference between comments and answers... It was made so that you could do some more research to understand what you face.

Comment: @SolarMike Oh, sorry for the ambiguity... "not very detailed" is not a complaint about your comment at all.  I was just responding to your question "How detailed is the work you are planning?", by writing "Not very detailed".

Consider for example the idea of <https://youtu.be/rqWm8obOU_A> .  I'd like to do that, but (1) I want to see inside without needing a camera, and (2) I want to do fun things like stuff those compressed marshmallows inside a (tubeless) bike tire.

Comment: When I asked "How detailed is the work you are planning? Threading needles is unlikely - how would you pick up the thread or needle? fitting a 20mm nut to a bolt is more achievable" it was about what WORK or ACTIVITY you wish to do, not the state of your design.